# Draw multiple circles using graphics in java

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I'm working on a connect four game and I'm trying to get multiple circles to show up when I click on the screen. Right now, every time I make a new click, the circle I just drew disappears.

Any help is appreciated.

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;    // create 2d object
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));  // set thickness of line

        // each box is 100 x 100
        // draws the vertical lines
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            g2d.drawLine(140 + i * DISC_RADIUS, 30, 140 + i * DISC_RADIUS, 690);
        }
        // draws the horizontal lines
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            g2d.drawLine(140, 90 + i * DISC_RADIUS, 840, 90 + i * DISC_RADIUS);
        }
        // draws the circles
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {       // new vertical row of circles
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {   // new horizontal row of circles
                g2d.drawOval(140 + j * DISC_RADIUS, 90 + i * DISC_RADIUS, DISC_RADIUS, DISC_RADIUS);
            }
        }

        // if at the start of the game, will not draw the counters
        if (start == true) {
            // draws blue counter
            g2d.drawOval(20, 90, DISC_RADIUS, DISC_RADIUS);
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);       // sets colour to blue
            g2d.fillOval(20, 90, DISC_RADIUS, DISC_RADIUS); // draws the circle

            // draws red counter
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.drawOval(875, 90, DISC_RADIUS, DISC_RADIUS);
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);            // sets the colour to red
            g2d.fillOval(875, 90, DISC_RADIUS, DISC_RADIUS);    // draws the circle


        }
        //print on the screen who's turn it is


        // draws blue counter stand;
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));  // sets the line width
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);          // changes the outline colour to black
        g2d.drawPolygon(poly1);             // draw the outline
        g2d.setColor(Color.GRAY);           // changes the fill colour to grey
        g2d.fillPolygon(poly1);             // draws the filling

        // draws bred counter stand;
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);  // changes the outline colour to black
        g2d.drawPolygon(poly2);     // draws the outline
        g2d.setColor(Color.GRAY);   // changes the fill colour to grey
        g2d.fillPolygon(poly2);     // draws the filling

        repaint();

        if(Player.getPlayer() == "Blue"){
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);  
            if(draw == true){
                g2d.drawString("Blue's Turn", 40, 300); 
                g2d.drawOval(xPos, yPos, DISC_RADIUS, DISC_RADIUS);
                g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);       // sets colour to blue
                g2d.fillOval(xPos, yPos, DISC_RADIUS, DISC_RADIUS); // draws the circle
            }
        }

        if(Player.getPlayer() == "Red"){
            g2d.drawString("Red's Turn", 900, 300);
            if(draw == true){
                g2d.drawOval(xPos, yPos, DISC_RADIUS, DISC_RADIUS);
                g2d.setColor(Color.RED);        // sets colour to blue
                g2d.fillOval(xPos, yPos, DISC_RADIUS, DISC_RADIUS); // draws the circle
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't update or modify the state of the UI directly or indirectly within a paint method (ie don't call repaint). Player.getPlayer() == "Red" is not how String comparison in Java works, use String#equals instead

Comment: Does your class implement `MouseListener`?

Comment: Also, remember, painting Is destructive, that is, each time paintCompoment is called, you are expected to completely repaint the state of the component from scratch

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Painting is destructive, that is, every time `paintComponent` is called, you are expected to repaint the entire state of the component from scratch.

What you should do is create some kind of model which maintains information about which player has which cell selected.

For example, you could just use a 2D array of `String`, where a `null` means no-body, `Red` is for red player and `Blue` is for blue player.  You would then use a simple compound loop to loop through the array and paint the UI accordingly...

Now, `if(Player.getPlayer() == "Blue"){` is not how `String` comparison works in Java, you should be using something more like `if("Blue".equals(Player.getPlayer())){` instead.

Don't update or modify the state of the UI from within any paint method directly or indirectly, this could setup an infinite loop of paint requests which will consume your CPU cycles...

Answer (score 0):

One shouldn't be calling `repaint()` from within the `paintComponent()` method, as `repaint()` will somehow call `paintComponent()`, thus leading to recursive calls.

Moreover, as call to `repaint()` takes place, the whole `JComponent` is actually painted from initial state. In order, for you to draw the circles already on the `JPanel/JComponent`, one can simply use a `Collection/Array` to keep track of what has been drawn. So that the code can iterate on this `Collection/Array` to redraw all circles previously drawn and the new circle that is to be drawn.

Here is small sample example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CircleExample {

    private static final int GAP = 5;

    private JPanel drawingBoard;    

    private void displayGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Circle Drawing Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(GAP, GAP));
        contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));

        drawingBoard = new DrawingBoard();
        contentPane.add(drawingBoard);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new CircleExample().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}

class DrawingBoard extends JPanel {

    private static final int WIDTH = 300;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 350;

    private List<MyCircle> circles;
    private Random random;

    private MouseAdapter mouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
            System.out.println("Mouse Clicked");
            int x = me.getX();
            int y = me.getY();
            circles.add(new MyCircle(x, y, getRandomColour()));
            DrawingBoard.this.repaint();
        }
    };

    public DrawingBoard() {
        super();
        circles = new ArrayList<MyCircle> ();
        random = new Random();
        setOpaque(true);
        addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (MyCircle circle : circles) {
            circle.drawCircle(g);
        }
    }

    private Color getRandomColour() {
        return new Color(random.nextFloat(), random.nextFloat(),
                            random.nextFloat(), random.nextFloat());
    }
}

class MyCircle {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private Color backgroundColour;

    private static final int RADIUS = 20;

    public MyCircle(int x, int y, Color backgroundColour) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.backgroundColour = backgroundColour;
    }

    public void drawCircle(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(backgroundColour);
        g.fillOval(x, y, RADIUS, RADIUS);
    }
}
```